# Browser Compatibility Issues With Java

Tags: java, browser, java-web-start, japplet

**Java Compatibility**

I have been having some trouble with making a custom browser I am using a default class provided by oracle for a custom browser. One thing I noticed with the browser is that it cannot run java applets without some sort of variation of java browser plugins. How exactly do normal browsers receive information from a web server to run a java program externally? Is there any way to somehow point the browser toward the jre to run the app like on a normal browser. Just need somewhere to start. FireFox apparently references some sort of MIME format under the npjp2.dll native found in the jre directory. Thanks Very Much.

[Oracle Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the user with a standard html download page in order for him to download a JNLP file which is the standard file to start a java web start app (applet). If the user's system has java installed, it must recognize the .jnlp file and assosiate it as a java app. It's an extra step, for the user to manually download the file instead of running automatically on a web browser, however because of recent security loopholes on java web implementations, most browsers don't trust java anymore, therefore the blocking. If you insist on setting up a web start app in a browser you must make sure that all users have appropriate security configurations on ther java installation (very unlikely).

EDIT:

Here's a very nice tutorial on how to achieve what I just explained.

[TUTORIAL](http://www.tentackle.org/html/en/t_webstart.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I am having a hard time understanding. So the .jnlp file is just a reference for the applets running java? If this were true how does my custom browser using .jnlp reference a jar that it knows nothing about? Is that what the RMI is for and if not how at all does the browser communicate.

Comment: Also, Is there any other way to do it other than using third parties just strictly java, html, or javascript?

Comment: Have you looked into the contents of your JNLP file? Please note that you're using Java FX, which you can configure to run on local mode (no need of a server or RMI) as a standard Java app, or as a Web Start application that needs remote resources. You can achieve this by editing certain fields in your JNLP file, so, when a user execute the file, the java web start engine is going to look for either local (local jars, libraries, etc.) or remote resources (remote jars, RMI services, etc).

Comment: how would you get JWS to look for the remote jars?

Comment: As just mentioned, it all depends on how you configure your JNLP file. Here's another nice tutorial to set up a server to provide remote resources to a Web Start application. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/